# Rails 4.2 Unable to run rails c in staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, staging

I deployed my application, it serves pages, when I issue `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake routes` it shows its routes, but when I issue `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rails c` it only shows help banner:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice

...

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

And bin folder is empty. How to make it start `rails c` ?

Comment: run  `rake rails:update:bin`